# How can I save a javascript variable to a SQL database?

Tags: database, sqlite

In my javascript code I have it set up so that a canvas is saved to a javascript variable, like so:

```
function saveImage() {
    var scanvas = document.getElementById("staff");
    scanvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasData = scanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

I want to have it so that someone who wants to save that image can save it to their account on the database. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score -2):

If it is the URL you need to save, have a hidden variable inside form tag.

```
<input id="canvasData" type="hidden" name="staff" value="" />
```

and in your script,

```
document.getElementById('canvasData').value = staff;
```